# Almost everywhere continuity of $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, continuity, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that 
$\begin{cases} 
1 & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\\
0 & x\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$

1. Show that $f$ is not continuous almost everywhere.
2. Show that $f$ is almost everywhere equal to a continuous function.

---

For (1) I got a bit confused

$f$ is continuous at $a$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $$|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$$

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, with $\delta_a$. Consider $\epsilon < 1$. Then supposedly $|x-a|<\delta_a$ implies 
$$|f(x)-f(a)| < 1 $$

But $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so there exists $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x_0-a|<\delta_a$ and yet
$$|f(x_0)-f(a)| = 1 \nless 1 $$

So $f$ is not continuous at any irrational number. In fact using the same reasoning, $f$ is not continuous at any rational number either. Hence it is not continuous almost everywhere.

For (2) you note that $g(x) :=1$ is continuous
$$f = g \quad\text{almost everywhere}$$
because 
$\{x : f(x)\neq g(x)\} = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mu(\mathbb{Q})=0$

**Do these arguments make sense?**

Comment: Both look good to me, although as mentioned $|x-a|$ can be degenerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but in your definition of continuity, you should replace $0<|x-a|<\delta$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. Also, in your argument, you should specify that you are taking $\epsilon<1$ and then let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary, since you are trying to show that $\exists>0$ $\forall\delta>0$ there is an $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

You are also correct in stating that a similar argument proves that $f$ is not continuous at any $\mathbb{Q}$ and, hence, is in fact nowhere continuous.

Comment: I understand your second point. Can you tell me the difference between including and excluding the $0<$ in the definition of continuity? I thought you would want to include it to show that $|x-a|$ is greater than zero, but I guess if $\delta > 0$ that is always the case, anyway?

Comment: In the definition of the limit in general, yes. However, the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity of $f$ at $a$ is: $\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. This is precisely because of the fact that for continuity, one has $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$.